# Alter Field Type from nvarchar(255) to nvarchar(Max) in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to alter column type in table `stk020`. So, I used this query..

```
ALTER TABLE [stk020] 
ALTER COLUMN [t16] nvarchar(Max) not null
```

The original column type of `[t16]` is `nvarchar(255)`. I get this error

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'DF_*STK020*_t16__725CC34D' is dependent on column 't16'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN t16 failed because one or more objects access this column.

Any solution?

Comment: change the default constraint 'DF_STK020_t16__725CC34D'

Answer (score 6):

You must first drop what we presume is the Default constraint on the column before you alter its data type:

```
Alter Table stk020 Drop Constraint DF_STK020_t16__725CC34D
GO
Alter Table stk020 Alter Column t16 nvarchar(max) not null
GO
Alter Table stk020 Add Constraint DF_STK020_t16__725CC34D
    Default ... For t16
```

Comment: And of course, it would be useful to use a **more meaningful name** for the default constraint, like `DF_STK020_T16` or something like that, rather than use the mangled and hard to read system name

Comment: @marc_s - It would also be useful to have a more meaningful name for the column...

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution.I can solve this problem :)

Comment: @Thomas: yes, absolutely - I agree!